# Terraform - How to enable API Gateway execution logging?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

### Question

How to setup API Gateway stage level execution logging with Terraform? Is it not supported yet?

### Background

API Gateway stage editor has the [execution logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html) configurations. However, it seems there is no parameter to set them in [aws_api_gateway_stage](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_stage.html) although it has [access loggging](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/api_gateway_stage.html#access_log_settings) configuration parameters.

Wondering if there are another resources to use or simply those parameters have not been implemented.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use `aws_api_gateway_method_settings` ...

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "YOUR_settings" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.YOUR.id}"
  stage_name  = "${aws_api_gateway_stage.YOUR.stage_name}"
  method_path = "*/*"
  settings {
    logging_level = "INFO"
    data_trace_enabled = true
    metrics_enabled = true
  }
}
```

the CloudWatch LogGroup should look like 
`API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_{YOU_API_ID}/{YOU_STAGENAME}`

... maybe you have to setup all the IAM role stuff ...

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to configure that log group name to be something more customised and transparent to it's purpose? I have a problem that in the future I'll have multiple api-gateway projects and I want to name them accordingly

Comment: The key thing to note is that the method_part determines whether the settings are for the whole stage or only for a specific method in that stage. When method_part is set to "*/*" then the aws_api_gateway_method_settings determines the settings for the whole stage.   Documentation has this "method_path - (Required) Method path defined as {resource_path}/{http_method} for an individual method override, or */* for overriding all methods in the stage."

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, that's how you "setup all the IAM role stuff" mentioned in the accepted answer by @dasrick:

```
# Allow API Gateway to push logs to CloudWatch
resource "aws_api_gateway_account" "main" {
  cloudwatch_role_arn = aws_iam_role.main.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "main" {
  name = "api-gateway-logs-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "main" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.main.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
}
```

This policy already exists in AWS as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html#set-up-access-logging-permissions).

Answer (score 1):

You can set these logging levels either at the entire "stage" level or override the stage level and define it at the method level as in this example: (notice the "method_path" value here)

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_settings" "s" {
rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.test.id
stage_name  = aws_api_gateway_stage.test.stage_name
method_path = 
"${aws_api_gateway_resource.test.path_part}/${aws_api_gateway_method.test.http_method}"

settings {
metrics_enabled = true
logging_level   = "INFO"
}
}
```

Found here:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_settings

See also here:

- https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4448